# Sequential clustering with Carrot2?

Tags: cluster-analysis, carrot2

its possible to do "sequential clustering" with carrot2.
What i mean with sequential clustering is, let say I have a set of documents that im clustering, and then after a some time new documents are ariving for clustering, is it possible to cluster new document with the old result or do I need to recluster all documents.

first post btw so be be gentle.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but what you refer to is usually called 'online clustering'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carrot2 does not support such operation mode out of the box. Depending on how frequently new documents arrive, you may be able to recluster a sliding window of documents and merge the newly created clusters with the old ones to get the complete result. I haven't tried such an arrangement before, so if it fails, you may indeed be better off with a dedicated online clustering algorithm.